# Version RELEASE or LATEST for parent pom

Tags: maven

From maven 3.5.2, the following warning is displayed if a dependency's version is set to `RELEASE` or `LATEST`:

> [WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for <groupId>:<artifactId>:jar is either LATEST or RELEASE (both of them are being deprecated)

This warning is **not** given if the pom's *parent* version is set to e.g. `RELEASE`:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>
    <artifactId>base</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Is this intentional, so that we can safely continue to rely on `RELEASE` version for the parent pom?

Our use case is that we host a service for ~100 tenants that need a common set of profiles and some dependency management etc. This common configuration is defined in our 'base' pom which is used as parent by each tenant's pom. We need all tenants to use the same version, and the latest released version, of our parent pom.

Comment: No you shouldn't cause it looks like this has simply being missed. Created a [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6342) for that...cause it should be removed as well...

Comment: @khmarbaise, from which maven version do you expect that support for LATEST and RELEASE will be removed?

Comment: At least starting with Maven version 3.5.3 will emit warnings about it's usage...complete remove ?...I can't say at the moment..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We had a similar situation: We have parent poms that are used by hundreds of projects by dozens of developers. In Ant, we had an approach similar to the RELEASE one, but now we have explicit version numbers.

Every developer needs to run `versions:update-parent` to get the new version, otherwise he/she stays with the old one. The disadvantage is that several versions of the parent pom are in use, the advantage is build stability because the "parent pom people" cannot destroy the builds by a wrong configuration that is drawn implicitly.

In your case, I would advice you to think whether you *really* need everybody to use the same version. If you really need this, you probably have to use *version ranges* as `[1.0.0,)`.

Comment: Thanks @JF Meier! But please note that the version range needs an upper bound when a relativePath is not given.

Comment: @gjoranv What exactly do you mean? What is wrong about my version range?

Comment: I have to add an upper bound, e.g. [1,2). If not, I get this error message:  
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM com.ourdomain:base:[1,) for com.ourdomain-theirapp:1.0.1: The requested parent version range '[1,)' does not specify an upper bound and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line x, column y

Comment: Dependencies don't require the upper bound, but parent poms apparently do when using version range. My experience has been the same as @gjoranv when using a parent pom that's pulled in from a private repo instead of locally; without the upper bound, the build fails.